# Как создать линк (hard or symbolic) в любом каталоге на /emulated/0?

Tags: android

Я догадываюсь, что это происки моей операционной системы /андроид 6.0.1/, но как я не пытался, но создать символический линк в /emulated/0 и/или любом его подкаталоге я не смог, идет сообщение **readonly access**, один раз я умудрился создать hard link на текстовый файл, но повторить это я не  могу... Почему я пытаюсь сделать это?
Мое любимое приложение Readera всю вспомогательную информацию хранит в каталоге /emulated/0/ReadEra, ну моя библиотека насчитывает около 10 тысяч книг, и объем этого каталога уже 1-1.5 GB. Хотелось перекинуть его на SD карту, так как объем внутренней памяти очень маленький. Приложение LinkSD его не перемещает, а ручками сделать не удается. В тоже время Total Commander (**ТТ**), DArchiver спокойно создают каталоги и файлы в /emulated/0 и его каталогах!!!
**Было бы здорово, если бы было приложение для создания линков**. К тому же SD-карта подразумевает другое устройство с другими разделами, и символический линк дает ошибку **Cross-device link**.
Также было бы интересно, можно ли сделать линк, который в свою очередь ссылается на другой линк? Вроде создавать он создается, но будет ли он работать, не знаю... Один линк на текстовый файл при открытии в **ТТ** показывает текстовый файл, а линк на линк на текстовый файл показывает какую-то ерунду.

С уважением,
Радмир.

Comment: Не знаю как вы умудрились, но FAT32 вообще не поддерживает ссылки, и тем более на внешнюю карту разрешение писать файлы не действует для приложения. Как вариант, можно поменять внутреннюю и внешнюю карты местами, в некоторых аппаратах это даже предусмотрено производителем и имеется соответствующая настройка. А лучше обновить (пропатчить) саму читалку, чтобы она писала куда надо.

Comment: @woesss, а откуда вообще fat32?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а во что форматируются SD карты и пользовательский раздел в аппарате?

Comment: @woesss, так ссылка на карту, а сама ссылка на файловой системе внутреннего раздела. Не знаю, во что он форматируется, но 90%, что не FAT32, а какой-нибудь из ext. Карта может быть в fat32, но кажется, что это неважно для ссылки? Плюс, подозреваю, что карту можно и во что-то другое отформатировать. У меня карта не в fat32 - на неё писалось видео экрана больше 4 гигов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, зачем спорите, если не знаете - возьмите да проверьте. Я на нескольких аппаратах пытался выставить "только чтение" и нигде не удалось. Для какой-нибудь из ext это ведь не проблема? Даже если возможности ФС игнорирует сам Андроид где-то на программном уровне, то не вижу смысла форматировать во что-то съедающее полезную ёмкость больше чем FAT, тем более что задачи как у ТС не типичны для мобильных устройств. Сам Андроид у меня показывает sdcardfs - насколько я понял это эмуляция и что там на самом деле неизвестно.

Comment: @woesss, во-первых, я не спорю, а рассуждаю. Во-вторых, чтобы проверить, надо достать карту из телефона, а мне не хочется. Ну и в-третьих, вопрос про влияние файловой системы на карте на создание ссылки по-прежнему актуален. Насколько я знаю, ссылки должны поддерживаться той фс, на которой они создаются, а не той, на которую указывают - разве нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, разве я говорил что ФС карты влияет на создание ссылки на неё саму? ТС пытался создать ссылку во встроенном хранилище, где тоже FAT. Но не совсем - FAT эмулируется для приложений через FUSE или SDcardFS (в зависимости от версии ОС) поверх реальной ФС. А какая там на самом деле - для нас роли не играет, так как прямой доступ к ней мы не имеем.

Answer (score 2):

**Что я обнаружил:**

Поскольку объем каталога `/emulated/0/ReadEra` у меня составляет более 1 Гб, то эксперименты я начал с этого каталога.

Оказывается, можно скопировать каталог  на раздел *ext4* внешней SD карты с сохранением всех прав разрешений.

Делать это лучше всего с помощью приложения darchiver, total commander не имеет прав на раздел ext4 внешней SD карты, и даже скопировать уже имеющуюся там копию скопировать не может, а как дать права ему я не знаю.

Можно сделать символический линк на эту копию где-нибудь в `/data`, например, в `/data/local/tmp`.

Затем я попытался скопировать этот линк в `/emulatted/0` и мне удалось скопировать линк на простой текстовый файл, и он работает,

При нажатии на него выдается содержимое файла, на который линк указывает, но при копировании линка на каталог, как в нашем случае, копируется просто содержимое каталога, а не линк! Возможно это связано с тем, что копия находится в другом разделе (partition), отличном от раздела каталога `/emulated/0/ReadEra`!

**Тем самым моя задача подставить линк вместо каталога не решена.**

Пришлось заглянуть в содержимое `/emulated/0/ReadEra`. Оказалось, в нем два подкаталога `Backups` и `Covers`; первый содержит резервные копии, а второй маленькие фото, называемые *thubnails*.

И я просто удалил все копии кроме последней на сегодня и все *thumbnails*. Проверил запуском приложения *readera*, пока работает! Посмотрим, что будет дальше.

В итоге я сэкономил 1 Гб внутренней памяти, стало легче дышать! Как видите ларчик просто открывался.